# Python program via command prompt not allowing > or < as inputs

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd

I'm trying to input a string of data that includes characters like > , < , = into my python program.
code:

```
user_input=input("Input data here")
```

input:

```
2>
```

However, when I run this via command prompt I get this

```
File "<string>", line 1
2>
 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I'm able to get this working fine by running the code in jupyter console or idle... I can even get it to work by inputting `"2>"`, but I can't expect my users to run this in anything other than command prompt or put in the quotation marks.

Is there any possible solution here?

Comment: I suspect it's running in python 2 from cmd. See if `raw_input` works when run from the command window

Comment: was not able to recreate this in windows cmd using `python 3.x`

Comment: @roganjosh Yep was able to recreate it by running python 2.x from cmd

Comment: Ah! @roganjosh you are correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function is used to get data from the user in **Python Command Line programs**.  You can use `raw_input`, it takes the input from the standard input in the form of a string and reads the data from a line at once.

```
user_input = raw_input('Input data here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Error on my end... Python 2.7 was apparently set to the default for running files.
Solved by changing path of python via:

```
ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Otherwise, if I wanted to use Python 2.7 I could fix this with

```
user_input=raw_input("insert data here")
```